# Sort list by priority

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, priority-queue

How I can define a function priority_sort() that return a sorted list with its items in ascending order but prioritize the elements in the set over the other items in the list.

If the list is empty, return an empty list.
If the set is empty there is nothing to prioritize, but the list should still be sorted.
The set may contain values that are not in the list.
The list may contain duplicates.
The list and the set will only contain integer values.

Example

```
priority_sort([], {2, 3}) == []
priority_sort([], {}) == []
priority_sort([1, 2, 3], {}) == [1, 2, 3]
priority_sort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1], {3, 6}) == [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
priority_sort([1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1], {1, 5}) == [1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2]
priority_sort([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0], {-4, -3}) == [-4, -3, -5, -2, -1, 0]
```

My code

```
def priority_sort(unsort_lst, pri_set):
pri_set1 = list(pri_set)
new_list = sorted([i for i in unsort_lst if not i in pri_set1])
if unsort_lst == []:
    return []

for i in pri_set1:
    if i not in unsort_lst:
        pri_set1.remove(i)
return pri_set1 + new_list
```

But the test priority_sort([1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1], {1, 5}) == [1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2] return False

Comment: Please make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If you're having trouble, post your code and ask about how to improve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just make two lists, sort them separately, and concatenate:

```py
>>> xs = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
>>> S = {-4, -3}
>>> in_S = [x for x in xs if x in S]
>>> not_in_S = [x for x in xs if not x in S]
>>> list(sorted(in_S)) + list(sorted(not_in_S))
[-4, -3, -5, -2, -1, 0]
```

Alternately you can define a custom comparison function which maps each value to a tuple where the first element is a boolean representing whether the value is in the set, and the second element is the value itself:

```py
>>> list(sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (not x in S, x)))
[-4, -3, -5, -2, -1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
def priority_sort(items, priorities):
    def get_score(item):
        if item in priorities:
            return min_val - 1
        else:
            return item

    if not items:
        return items

    min_val = min(items)
    items = sorted(items)
    return sorted(items, key=get_score)
    
    
assert priority_sort([], {2, 3}) == []
assert priority_sort([], {}) == []
assert priority_sort([1, 2, 3], {}) == [1, 2, 3]
assert priority_sort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1], {3, 6}) == [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
assert priority_sort([1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1], {1, 5}) == [1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2]
assert priority_sort([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0], {-4, -3}) == [-4, -3, -5, -2, -1, 0]
```

How does it work? We first sort it normally and then handle the priorities. Each element is scored and if the element is in priority, it gets the lowest score, and this score is one minus the minimum.